# Excel Formula to return everything after a specific set of characters in a string up to but not including the next number character in a string?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Excel 2007

I have a string in cell A1 and I need a formula to go in B1 to look at the string and find a specific character `)` and the next numerical (number) character after the characters kHz and return all characters in between the two.

It must not return the `)` and the numerical character after this as they are just acting as delimiters.

The `kHz` is part of the returned result (and should be returned as part of it) but as it remains constant and will not change it also acts a good reference for the formula to use when looking for the first numerical character after this.

String example

```
Gjj2826)_48_kHz_16jouioj
```

So I want the formula to extract and return `_48_kHz_`

The `)` is always going to be a `)` and will not change.

The `16jouioj` will change but the first character will always be a number.

The `_48_kHz_` will change, it could be `_244_kHz_` or `_4_kHz_` hence the need to something as delimiters that sit on either side of the text that I need.

Thank you

Comment: `4` is a number, by your definition of `next numerical` it should only return `_`

Comment: is it always 4 grouping delimited with `_`?

Comment: the 4 grouping is part of a string which has _ where they would normally be spaces `" "`

Comment: Is it always `4` and you want the second and third?

Comment: From the `)` there will always be four `_`

Answer (score 1):

The three extracted texts that you gave all contained "kHz", so I believe this should work:

```
=LEFT(MID($A1,FIND("_",$A1,1),LEN($A1)),FIND("kHz",MID($A1,FIND("_",$A1,1),LEN($A1)),1)+3)
```

[image]

Edit:

Since your actual text string is much more complicated than the answers in your post, Wasif Hasan's answer is closer to what you need, but the pattern is not entirely correct, nor is the usage of the matches object (I think).

Create a new module in your workbook (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the Visual Basic Editor, then right-click the Modules node of the VBAProject that refers to your current workbook and select 'Insert>Module':

[image]

Paste this code into the module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetFrequency(ByRef r As Range) As String

    Dim regex As Object

    Set regex = CreateObject("VbScript.RegExp")

    With regex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "_[0-9]+?_kHz_"
        GetFrequency = .Execute(r).Item(0).Value
    End With

End Function
```

You can then use the function in your workbook. For example:

```
=GetFrequency(A2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Owen your code returns a '#VALUE!" error ?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion over kHz - I have edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: I'm not sure what confusion you mean. Anyway, could you add a screenshot of your data, your error and that shows the formula in the formula bar?

Comment: Works perfectly. Nicely done

Comment: The site will not let me post a image - how do I do it, the image is on Imgur?

Comment: You can just insert the link to your image into the post, or I think if you copy and try to paste the image into your post, it will do that for you if you don't have reputation to use images.

Comment: Thanks Owen - Here's a link [link](https://imgur.com/a/ucjvk17)

Comment: I've adapted my answer to the more complicated text string in your image.

Comment: Brilliant Owen, that works, thank you. I am still learning formulas and not even tried VBA yet so you have my gratitude. I do not want to push it but using your example - is it possible to remove the `"_"` from the results and then trim the space `" "` from each side of the returned value so it looks like `55 kHz` or `160 kHz` or what ever the kHz value of a given line in my spread sheet might be?

Comment: `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(GetFrequency(A2),"_"," "))`

If that works for you, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Added the code you suggested and tried on 10 test entries in Column A and it returned #VALUE! for rows 1 - 7 but works on rows 8 - 10. If I remove Substitute code and then just use the original GetFrequency call all 10 return then return the #VALUE!?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109129/discussion-between-owen-and-kenny).

Answer (score 1):

Excel formula FIND does not support regex then you have to use VBA:

```
Sub Exec()
  Static reg as Object
  Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")
  reg.Global = True
  reg.IgnoreCase = False
  reg.Pattern = ".+\)(_\d+_\w+_).+"
  Dim matches As Object
  Set matches = reg.Execute(Range("A1").Value)
  Range("B1").Value = matches.item(0).submatches.item(0)
End Sub
```